# Conteúdo de Página não aparece no Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin

Estou tendo problemas para mostra o conteúdo das páginas. Criei um ListView com algumas opções, segue o código abaixo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace testeVale.Views
{
    public class Menu
    {
        public string itemMenu { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public List<Menu> Itens { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Itens = new List<Menu>
            {

            new Menu { itemMenu = "Sobre Nós"},
            new Menu { itemMenu = "Cidades" },
            new Menu { itemMenu = "Eventos" },
            new Menu { itemMenu = "Contato" }

            };
            this.BindingContext = this;            
        }

         void ListViewMenu_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var menu = (Menu) e.Item;
            if (menu.itemMenu is "Sobre Nós")
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new sobreNos(menu));
            }
            if (menu.itemMenu is "Contato")
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new contato(menu));
            }
            /*DisplayAlert("Menu", string.Format("Você tocou no modelo'{0}'", menu.itemMenu),"Fechar");*/
        }
    }
}
```

Na página "Sobre Nós" por exemplo, estou tentando exibir o conteúdo mas só está mostrando o botão 'voltar'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace testeVale.Views
{
    public partial class sobreNos : ContentPage
    {
        public sobreNos(Menu opcao)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Title = opcao.itemMenu;
            var label = new Label { Text = "This is a label." };
        }

        private void buttonVoltar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
        }
    }
}
```

Também tentei pelo xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="testeVale.Views.sobreNos">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="5,10">
            <Label TextColor="#77d065" FontSize = "20" Text="Sobre Nós" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
    <Button x:Name="buttonVoltar" Text="Voltar" Clicked="buttonVoltar_Clicked" VerticalOptions="End"></Button>

</ContentPage>
```

Não aparece nada, somente o botão, o que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 2):

O arquivo sobreNos.xaml deveria estar assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="testeVale.Views.sobreNos">
    <StackLayout Padding="5,10">
        <Label TextColor="#77d065" FontSize = "20" Text="Sobre Nós" />
        <Button x:Name="buttonVoltar" Text="Voltar" VerticalOptions="End" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Caso queira implementar via código C#, ficaria assim:

```
    public class sobreNos : ContentPage {

        public sobreNos() {
            Content = new StackLayout {
                Padding = new Thickness(5, 10),
                Children = {
                    new Label { Text = "Sobre Nós", TextColor = Color.FromHex("#77d065"), FontSize = 20  },
                    new Button { Text = "Voltar", VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End }
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Coloquei dentro do Stacklayout e apareceu o conteúdo, qual é a função deste comando? É similar ao LinearLayout do Android? Sempre que eu quiser colocar um conteúdo precisará ficar dentro deste termo?

Comment: O **StackLayout** organiza suas views (Buttons, Labels...) em uma linha de uma dimensão - seja horizontal ou vertical, um embaixo do outro ou um ao lado do outro. Se quiser que as views fiquem nesta disposição, o mais indicado é usar o **StackLayout**. Sugiro uma lida em [Layouts -
 Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts)